# Uniqueness of smallest element in poset

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, relations, order-theory

*Prove that a smallest element, if it exists, is determined uniquely.*

This is follows directly for definition. An element $a \in X$ is called the smallest element of $(X, \preceq)$ if for every $x \in X$  we have $a \preceq x$. Suppose was some other element $b \in X$ for which for every $x \in X$ we would have  $b \preceq x$, but then $a \preceq b$ could not hold, unless $a=b$.

Is this really simple proof correct?

Comment: It's correct, personally I'd write it like this: Let $a,b$ be smallest elements. Since $a$ is a smallest element, one has in particular $a\leq b$. Similarly $b\leq a$. By anti-symmetry $a=b$ follows, proving uniqueness.

Comment: ah, ok, so you are using the fact that every poset is antisymmetric by definition. thank you.

Comment: And so are you, otherwise you can't say that "$a \preceq b$ could not hold, unless $a=b$". The real difference between what I wrote and what you wrote is that you proved it by contradiction and I did not.